# Вывод сообщения об отключенном JS

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста! 
У меня есть веб-форма, в ней осуществляется проверка полей с помощью JavaScript. Необходимо выводить на страницу предупреждающее сообщение, если у пользователя отключена в настройках браузера обработка JS скриптов.

Comment: [noscript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Тег [noscript](http://htmlbook.ru/html/noscript) показывает сообщение при отключенном javascript-e.

> Контейнер `<noscript>` показывает свое содержимое, если браузер не поддерживает работу со скриптами или их поддержка отключена пользователем. В остальных случаях браузер игнорирует этот тег и все, что располагается внутри него.